# What's pupose for using the third [ ] in a 2D vector?

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<char>  T[3][4];  //this is a 2d vector table right?
vector<char> v;
for (int x = 0; x <3; x++)
{
  for (int y = 0; y <4; y++)
  {
    for (int z = 0; z <T[x][y].size(); z++) //T.[x][y].size() is the size of?
    {
      v.push_back(T[x][y][z]);  //Why we need use [z] for copying values in T to v?
    }                           //T is a 2D vector, it should only have two []'s, right?
  }
}
```

Hi,everyone. Here is a piece of C++ code wrote by my tutor, but I really confused about it. Please see the comment part in this code. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector<char>  T[3][4];  //this is a 2d vector table right?`

No, it is a 2D array of 1D vectors of `char`.

So in total it is 3D, which matches/supports the triple `[]` construct.

`for (int z = 0; z <T[x][y].size(); z++) //T.[x][y].size() is the size of?`

... the vector found at position x,y of the 2D array.

`v.push_back(T[x][y][z]);  //Why we need use [z] for copying values in T to v?`

What gets pushed to `v` is the content of index `z` in the vector found at the position x,y of the 2D array `T`.

Comment: Hi, Yunnosch. Thank you for helping me! Then I have two more questions.
1. If it's a 3D, why we initialize T only in two[ ]'s , but to copy it's value in 3 [ ]'s?
2.  Another piece of code: 

       T[row][col].push_back(v[i])

//Why when we copy v into T, we use only 2[ ]'s, but we use 3 [ ]'s by copying T into v?

Comment: Creating actual new questions, instead of cramming them into comments on an answer, will give you the space you need to explain in detail what you mean. That will really help with getting good answers. Do not misunderstand please, I will be happy to look at your new questions. But "moving target" questions are simply not appreciated on StackOverflow. Have fun.

Comment: Maybe you can phrase your new question like "I learned here (<link to this question>) that this is a 2D array of 1D vectors. Now I wonder why it only gets initialised like ( show an MRE ) instead of ( describe what you expect )." Compare [mre].

Comment: This really helps! Thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure. :-)